# Ignore specific characters in syntax matching

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a vim syntax highlighting file for a specific language. For some keywords, specific characters are ignored (`,` and `-`and `_`). In other words, these are exactly the same:

`foo` `f_oo` `f-o,o`

Is there a way I can ignore these characters when using eg. `syn match` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special option for this; you have you make a pattern which optionnally allows the specific chars between EACH char; example with `foo`:

```
f[,_-]*o[,_-]*o
```

Note that `-` *has* to be placed at the end of the `[]` block (see `:h /[]`).

As it is fastidious to write, you can create a function to make it for you:

```
func! CreatePattern(word)
    let l:s = ''
    let l:first = 1
    for i in range(len(a:word))
        if !l:first
            let l:s .= '[,_-]*'
        else
            let l:first = 0
        endif
        let l:s .= a:word[i]
    endfor
    return l:s
endf
```

After this, we have:

```
:echo CreatePattern('bar')
b[,_-]*a[,_-]*r
```

Then, you can use `:syn match` with the help of `:execute` :

```
:exe 'syn match MyHighlightGroup /'.CreatePattern('foo').'/'
```

or using `matchadd()` :

```
:call matchadd('MyHighlightGroup', CreatePattern('foo'))
```

Please note that the function above will only work with plain words, but it will break any pattern with contains special pattern chars. You may have to write a better function for such needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot - using a custom function seems to be the best solution here.